# What does "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'char'" mean? AVR

Tags: c, char, avr, progmem

```
// Sting for the Name
extern const PROGMEM char name[];

//Data structure of the Heap

typedef struct
{
  AllocStrategies strategy;
  uint16_t size;
  MemAddr start;
  MemDriver* driver;
  const PROGMEM char name[];
}Heap;
```

> expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__ attribute__' before 'char'

Why do i get this error message twice?

Comment: Because `PROGMEM` is what?

Comment: Because you miss an include... (Arduino?)

Comment: "*expected bla before 'char'*" means that you placed something different then "*bla before 'char'*". So you want to check what's "*before 'char'*" and how it differs from "*bla*".

Comment: it means that you need to code everything in asm from now on :)

Comment: more seriously the compiler is lost at this point. This is probably because `PROGMEM` isn't defined

Comment: Have a look at this: [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/). As already said: The definition of `PROGMEM` is missing - probably because you didn't `#include` something necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include a file:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
```

The `PROGMEM` attribute that allows you to allocate a `const` variable in program space is defined there.

You are getting this error message twice because you are using `PROGMEM` twice.